# Laravel model - CRUD only with records where one column = certain value?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Suppose i have a laravel model that works with a certain (MySQL) database table.

Inside of this table there is a column named 'administration'. (example: could be 1, 2 or 3)

At the moment in my controller im using that modal with eloquent and inside of my eloquent statement i ask only to work with records (crud style) that have administration 2 for instance.

I think it should be possible to add 'where administration = x' to my model instead of my controller so that if i use the model in my controller i would just be dealing with records that have that administration set.

Is this possible? I have tried googling it but could not find an answer yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel uses [global scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#global-scopes) for this.

You would create a scope for the administration:

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Scopes;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
 
class AdministrationScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->where('administration', '=', 2);
    }
}
```

And then you add it as a global scope to the model

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use App\Scopes\AdministrationScope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class YourModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new AdministrationScope);
    }
}
```

Comment: John, many thanks for your help and for the very good explanation, i learned a new thing about laravel today! Works like a charm :-)

Comment: By the way, i forgot to ask, sorry. If i insert a new record through my  controller, i also have to add the administration to the record. Is there also a possibility to have the model auto insert the administration for updateOrCreate actions to that record instead of me providing it every time?

Comment: You could add it as a default value to the database column, or the following in your model: ‘protected $attributes = ['administration' => 2 ];’